# Block user registration by country ip range

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in MYSQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countryip` (
`ip_from` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ip_to` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`country_iso2` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`country_iso3` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`country_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
KEY `ip_from` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`)) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

And here i have added the entire ip ranges of all countries in the world.

I want to make in php a script that will compare the user ip with the ip range from this database and after that echo a message.
From what i undestood i need to start by declaring

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db("database_name")   or die(mysql_error());
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `IP` FROM `ban_ip` WHERE `IP` = '$ip'"); // this works only if i have the single static ip in the dbs, but now i have the ip range
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
echo ' <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> alert("You are not allowed to access this website"); window.location.replace("index.php"); </script> </head> <body> </body> </html>';
    }
```

What can i do instead of this query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` = '$ip'");
```

in order to make possible the comparison between the User IP and the ip range.

And the IP FROM column, TO IP column looks like this
16777216, 16777471, 
In order to find out the ip there was a formula similar with ip = 256 + CLASS B * 256 + CLASS C * 256 * 256 + CLASS D * 256 * 256 * 256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following SQL query for the table you have specified:

```
SELECT `country_iso2` FROM `countryip` WHERE `ip_from` <= inet_aton('$ip') AND ip_to >= inet_aton('$ip')
```

This will select the two character country ISO code for the IP address that you have specified.  From here it is a simply matter of comparing the the ISO code with the entries from a banned country code table.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not an direct answer to your question, but I used this API lately;

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

Very easy to use with JSON and also fast reply from the server. It's free, try it out, would save you some storage in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question, but maintaining IP database yourself is a bit of a hassle in my experience.

I have used MaxMind's free GeoLite2 database for this, as it is updated quite often and provides pretty precise results:

https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the PHP Extension API if you are concerned at all about [performance](http://www.maxmind.com/en/benchmark). You can get upwards of 7 million queries per second with the PHP (C API) extension. MySQL is not tuned for these types of queries and managing the changing IP address updates via SQL can become a pain point. Maxmind releases monthly updates that you can easily download.

I describe how to compile the extension, and how to use the mmdb databases in PHP to restrict countries by iso-3316 2-character codes here:

[Intro to Maxmind GeoLite2 with Kohana PHP](http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2014/03/10/intro-to-maxmind-geolite2-with-kohana/)

[image: Geolocate IP Address]